# can't properly fit poisson distribution in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

i'm trying to plot poisson distribution with python3, but i'm having a problem with properly fitting the dataset.
The function i have now is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.misc import factorial

#where valor is like [1,2,4,4,4,5,6,2,5,5,7,4,7,3,2,5,7,9,4,44,33,1,3,43,54,22,12,3,24,34,55,33]
data = valor 

entries, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(data, bins=len(data), alpha=0.6, color='g', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.2)

bin_middles = 0.5*(bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])

def poisson(k, lamb):
    return (lamb**k/factorial(k)) * np.exp(-lamb)

parameters, cov_matrix = curve_fit(poisson, bin_middles, entries) 


x_plot = np.linspace(0,  len(data), 1000)

plt.plot(x_plot, poisson(x_plot, *parameters), 'r-', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

where valor is a variable dataset send by user.

With this i try to plot the poisson distribution, using another plotting software i get this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doreh.png)

but the plot output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ePe.png).
As you can see, the poisson line don't fit properly as in the first one.
*Both datasets use the same patern of data.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! To make the example complete you should define/import `factorial` and  `curve_fit`. Without them it does not run. What do you mean by *adjust the line size*?

Comment: oh, i forgot those, the plot i generated was too small, when i plot this dataset using arena the plotting line stay on the "middle" of the histogram.
Now i don't know why i'm plotting wrong. i'm very lost on the statistics side.

Comment: Can you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43868662/edit) your post to include the missing stuff? The particular functions used might actually be the cause of the problem. As I still don't quite understand the question it might be helpful if you could show an example or a sketch of the result you expect.

Comment: I think the fit is probably fine. The height of the histogram bars and your Poisson probability distribution don't match as the histogram displays counts, not probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [OpenTURNS](http://www.openturns.org/)' `PoissonFactory` which has a `build` method which returns the Poisson distribution that fits the data.

```
import openturns as ot
data=[1,2,4,4,4,5,6,2,5,5,7,4,7,3,2,5,7,9,4,44,33,1,3,43,54,22,12,3,24,34,55,33]
sample = ot.Sample(data,1)
distribution = ot.PoissonFactory().build(sample)
distribution.drawPDF()
```

produces:

[image: Poisson Distribution]

More details on this topic at: http://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/_generated/openturns.PoissonFactory.html